# Mono Winforms WebBrowser Error - libgluezilla not found

Tags: .net, winforms, mono, opensuse

I am trying to use the mono webbrowser control in a WinForms application running on opensuse 12.3

The error that is shown is "libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed.

I have searched for the libgluezilla package in Yast and can not find it.

looking through the documentation for the Webbrowser control I am not sure whether the libgluezilla requirement has been superseded by the webkit-sharp package.

I have installed webkit-sharp however I still get the libgluezilla error.

Answer (score 0):

RPMs are available for earlier versions of opensuse e.g. 12.1 from http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/opensuse/12.1/x86_64/libgluezilla0-2.6-10.1.2.x86_64.html or other options at http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=libgluezilla0&srodzaj=3

libgluezilla0-2.6-10.1.2.x86_64 installs fine for me on opensuse 13.1 x86_64, however, the C#/WinForms application I installed it for then just gives a SIGGSERV stacktrace when I launch it under mono, so how useful libgluezilla will be for you is another matter.